# string and redis.String (redigo) type does not match in golang

Tags: go, redigo

I got stuck on this comparision:

```
fmt.Println("Sending: ", notification.Type, notification.Type == "sms", reflect.TypeOf(notification.Type))
```

this out puts as:

```
Sending: sms false string
```

This is the `Notification`type

```
type Notification struct {
    Done    bool   `redis:"done"`
    Message string `redis:"message"`
    Type    string `redis:"type"`
    ID      string `redis:"id"`
    Error   error
}
```

And this is how I create the `notification` struct

```
notification := &Notification{ID: notificationID}
notification.Type, err = redis.String(c.Do("GET", "notification:id:"+notification.ID+":type"))
```

My question is why `notification.Type == "sms"` is `false`

Comment: Print the using `fmt.Printf("Sending: %q %v %T\n", notification.Type, notification.Type == "sms", notification.Type)` to determine if notification.Type contains more than the bytes 's', 'm' and 's'.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you very much for pointing out. It was actually a typo in the data that adds additional breakpoint at the end of the string.